# Как вывести геометрическую прогрессию?

Tags: delphi, прогрессия

Пытался вывести геометрическую прогрессию

```
  b,q:real;
  n:Integer;
  sum:real;
begin
  n:=0;
  b:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
  q:=StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
  for n:=0 to n do
    sum:=(b*(1-q*n))/(1-q);
  Label1.Caption:=sum;
```

в чем ошибка? что не так?

Comment: При чём тут функциональное программирование и дискретная математика?

Comment: чисто для тегов

Comment: Так это вы нам скажите, почему вы считаете что тут есть ошибка? И в чем она выражается.

Comment: Я для этого и написал

Comment: товарищ исправил можете сравнить)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

дам ответ кусочком на кусочек ваш

```
b,q:real;
sum:real;
begin    
b:=StrToFloat(Edit1.Text);
q:=StrToFloat(Edit2.Text);
sum:=b/(1-q);
Label1.Caption:=FloatToStr(sum);
```

формула суммы бесконечно убывающей геометрической прогрессии.

Обязательное условие основание по модулю меньше единицы. И сумма бесконечная. Для конечной суммы нужно количество членов в придачу к имеющимся параметрам

Comment: Благодарю, Азиз! Сразу видно человек разбирается

Comment: Не за что благодарить, рад помочь. Если ответ помог то галочка под стрелками.